# VSC MongoDB extension could not connect to MongoDB Container created with docker compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, vscode-extensions

I've got the docker-compose code from the docker hub mongo official image https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo
The code is like this:

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```

I try to connect with Vscode extension for MongoDB but is no connecting to it
I use the connection link like this: `mongodb://root:example@172.24.0.2:27017/t`
where 172.24.0.2 is the container IP address and 't' is the name of database I created using mongo-express.
I read several posts like this on this site but no one worked, trying:

- to expose the 27017 pot from mongo container.
- to `network_mode: host` for mongo container, in this case the IP I used was localhost

I don't understand why so difficult to start working with MongoDB, does anybody have a real example about this?(I hope is not because I use Windows11)